# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am deploying my project on tomcat,then I am getting  this error "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'".

this is my web xml file
**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0"
 metadata-complete="true">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

my **HelloWeb-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint.controller" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

my Controller **HelloController.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

       return "hello";
    }
 }
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please suggest me what is wrong in code?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you are following the tutorial of [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm) - HelloWorld for Spring MVC. I have the same issue which happens because DispatcherServlet try to resolve.

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/
```

It should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello
```

(Put this in your web-browser)

Or it can be done another way (as suggested in that tutorial)

> You should note that in the given URL, HelloWeb is the application
>   name and hello is the virtual subfolder which we have mentioned in our
>   controller using @RequestMapping("/hello"). You can use direct root
>   while mapping your URL using @RequestMapping("/"), in this case you
>   can access the same page using short URL
>   `http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/` but it is advised to have different
>   functionalities under different folders.

in *HelloWorldController* class, you change this:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
```

to this:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
```

the result is that you can call `http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/` without any problem.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that HelloController.class is generated or not in your [PROJECT_NAME]\target\classes\com\tutorialspoint\controller folder. If not your java code is not compiled due to some compilation errors.

Please check all corresponding java classes used in HelloController.java.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a mapping for `/HelloWorld/` only `/hello/`

Go to your base application location `localhost:8080/myApp/` then go to `/hello` and your jsp should return.  So `localhost:8080/myApp/hello` where `myApp` is your war filename (assuming it's not root).

Comment: Thanks for replay...Issue is resolved because i forgot to write the code in **web.xml** 

`<context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>
       org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
 </listener>`